# Get the HTML table <thead> element using query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I would like to add columns to the heading section of my html table using jquery.
This is the definition of the table:

```
<table id="grid">
    <thead>
            <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And despite I tried to get the reference to append a new th element this way:

```
$("#grid thead").find("tr").append("<th> elem </th>");
```

I still haven't succeed to do it. What should I write to refer to the first row of the heading? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could also be shortened to `$("thead tr", "#grid").append("<th> elem </th>");`

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson and that would be slower. context search is converted to find .

Comment: @RoyiNamir A minor performance hit perhaps, but more compact and easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: I agree. but try asking to replace a string in regex , and 100K of comments - it is slow. so .....nevermind. just to notice..:-)

Comment: I bet there is no jquery included

Answer (score 1):

your code is ok

http://jsbin.com/ufiper/2/edit

are you sure ? see the example attached.

Answer (score 1):

The script clearly works when I adapted it to a standalone page. I added the script inline after the table.  So maybe you are using this in the head & need a `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()` to make sure the code is only executed when the page loads?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>thead test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#grid thead").find("tr").append("<th> elem </th>");
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't include CDATA cruft/dodgy doctypes in answers - remember you are encouraging someone to copy and paste your code! (edit: I've tidied)

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest – just seems a bit unfair to someone starting out – a lot of people pick up bad habits from when they first learn to code. CDATA for instance is only needed in an XML document – as HTML != XML unless you are using XHTML1.1 and application/xml+xhtml, this just isn't needed. Using the newest jQuery for Google's API means it won't be cached, negating the point of using it from them - always specify a version (at least a high level one like 1.9).

Comment: Things like `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"` are clearly wrong (I know they are common and are parsed OK, but it's clear that it should be `content="text/html" charset="utf-8"`. Similarly with the `type='text/javascript'` stuff – that's always been the default – why specify it? I guess that in short, the amount of talismanic stuff hanging around on websites everywhere needs to die. Arguments aside, it's not needed, in many cases has never been needed, and complicates things for beginners.

Comment: This isn't an 'attack' on you by the way – it just bothers me that code is still being written like this. I've asked on meta whether we should come up with a few tips for people answering. Also, out of interest, would you usually write code like that, or did you add it in because you felt you should include it on this site?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23454/discussion-between-rich-bradshaw-and-jakegould)

Comment: Actually I try to run this on a velocity template, in a function called after a ajax request is successful...

Comment: Sorry, I thought that chat thing would move all these comments into chat, away from here! Have a good day. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you've presented is correct. Since it still doesn't work for you, my best guess would be that you've placed this code within your `<head></head>`. Since the browser read your code top-down and any script gets execute as soon as it is read, at the time it reaches your script, the DOM is not ready, and therefor no element match your selector.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Move the code to the end of your body, just before your closing body-tag `</body>`. Then you know that the element you're selecting is in the DOM.
2. Wrap your code in a DOM-ready callback, to make sure that the DOM is ready before you execute the code.

Example using a DOM-ready callback:

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid thead").find("tr").append("<th> elem </th>");
});
```